# How can I decode a JSON string in an ASPX page?

Tags: php, asp.net, json, curl

I am posting data in the json format from my server to a remote server via an aspx
page, as demonstrated below:

```
function httpPost($url, $params) {

    $payload = json_encode($params);
    //echo $payload;die;
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($payload));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
    );

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
    //return json_decode($output, true);
}

$params = array(
    "type" => "1",
    "ApplicationNo" => "1234567",
    "Effdate" => '05-06-1987',
    "InstituionID" => 'E01',
    "CourseCode" => '091',
);

echo httpPost("http://someurl/RESPONSE.aspx", $params);
```

How do I parse the json string in the aspx page?

Comment: If the PHP code does work and a valid JSON string is transmitted to your ASPX page, the PHP code doesn't matter so much here. Can you tell us if the code actually works and what you already tried on the ASPX side?

Comment: You need to have a class with required properties matching with JSON keys ( out of key/value pair) and deserialize request. If you can `JSON` data, then I can help you out on this.

Comment: {"type":"1","ApplicationNo":"1234567","Effdate":"05-06-1987","InstituionID":"E01","CourseCode":"091"}

Comment: above is the json string i am passing.But want to know how to get it in asp.net

Comment: @user1755949, posted answer, check `how to receive JSON value`.

Comment: in php i am geeting this data in remote server by $jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); //read the HTTP body.
echo $jsonStr; But how to get it in aspx page?

Comment: whats ur json being posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value ( JSON ) string using following.

```
StreamReader strmreader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
string json_value = strmreader.ReadToEnd();
```

Then you need to create a class (mentioned below) with matching JSON keys, and deserialize `json_value` with that class, this will get you values.

```
public class JSONReceived
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationNo { get; set; }
    public string Effdate { get; set; }
    public string InstituionID { get; set; }
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then using following to deserialize.

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jsz = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
JSONReceived r_obj = jsz.Deserialize<JSONReceived>(json_value);
```

Now, you can access json value , using this `r_obj.type` etc...